# Expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<>

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Tengo una clase repositorio que implementa de otra un método para obtener todos mis clientes

```
@Repository
public class ClienteRepositoryImpl implements ClienteRepository{

    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<ClienteEntity> findAll() {

        return em.createQuery("from Cliente").getResultList();

    }

}
```

El problema es que en la linea del return me arroja el siguiente warning

> Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List

He buscado en distintos lugares y no me queda tan claro porque Java me arroja esto. He leído también algunas preguntas sobre el tema en ingles como por ejemplo ***[esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115692/how-to-avoid-type-safety-warnings-with-hibernate-hql-results)*** donde incluso se recomienda el uso de la etiqueta *@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")* como así también desactivar los warnings que no se pueden evitar, algo que para mi es una mala practica.

¿Como podría evitar este tipo de warning sin el uso de etiquetas como la mencionada?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes probar con una `TypedQuery`:

```
return em.createQuery("from Cliente", ClienteEntity.class).getResultList();
```

Comment: Leí algo de eso, y funciona. ¿Sabrías explicarme porque sucede el warning y porque esto lo soluciona?. Gracias.

Comment: Cuando no especificas el tipo `getResultList()` retorna un `List` sin tipo y el compilador no puede comprobar que el tipo es el correcto por lo que solo te lo advierte. Cuando usas una `TypedQuery` el `EntityManager` te asegura retornar un listado del tipo apropiado